# How do I wrap a text in SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, word-wrap

As shown in the photo, a cell in the `dataGridView` contains 2 lines and when I insert it into the Database it doesn't wrap. I checked the wrap option in `Tools --> options --> Test Editor --> all Language --> word wrap.` But the word wrap still not working. As you can see the wrapped line in the DataGridView becomes one line in the database. 
Any idea in how can I wrap the line?

I used this code to insert data from DataGridView into SQL Server database:

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCN-TOSH;Initial    Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");

    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Customer(Qty, Des, Price) values ('" + dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value + "', '" + dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value + "')");
    cm.Connection = cn;
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```

[image: Photo]

Comment: But if you read it back do you have the two lines back?

Comment: when i read it back i have it in one line (same as in database). any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter very much how your value is rendered by SQL Server Mgmt Studio's (SMMS's) result set viewer. That program has pretty basic abilities to display multi line text.

The real question is whether the value renders correctly in your application program after a round trip to the data base. If it does, all is well.

If it doesn't, you should try to figure out whether the information is being altered on the way to the database, or the way back.

I have often succeeded at that by using Copy to copy the text from SMMS, and then I paste it into a simple text editor. Then I drag the cursor to count spaces.

Comment: it is solved   thank you very much for your help sir